# Get a value from class within a controller rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rails-activerecord

The title is misleading but I'm not sure how to word this.I have a method

```
   def showlease
   @tenant = Tenant.find(params[:id])
   @lease = @tenant.lease


   respond_to do |format|
   format.html # show.html.erb
   format.xml { render :xml => @tenant }
   end
   end
```

So as you can see I have to tables tenant and lease. Is there a way I can extract a value from @lease? My lease table has a value called property_id which I want to get something along the lines of @lease.property_id. I then want to use this value to get the corresponding record in my other table called properties. Here is basically what I want in pseudo

```
@Property = Property.where(_id = (@lease.property_id)
```

Even if I could just do it from my view if that's possible something like

```
 <p> Firstname: <%= @tenant.name %></p>
 <p> LeaseStart: <%= @lease.lease_start %></p>
  <p> LeaseStart: <%= @property(@lease.property_id).address %></p>
```

EDIT:

Here are my models

```
class Lease < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :lease_end, :lease_start, :property_id, :tenant_id
  belongs_to :tenant
  belongs_to :property
end

class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address_line_1, :city, :county, :image, :rent
  has_one :lease
end

class Tenant < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :phone
  has_one :lease
end
```

Comment: Why can't you do @lease.property.address? If this is not okay for you, you can delegate the address method on the Lease model. `delegate :address, to: :property`

Comment: I edited it to show my models I can't get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as you have defined the associations in your models you don't need to find by ID, you can just ask for the associated object.

```
<%= @lease.property.address %>
```

Comment: Your models look like they will support calling the associated objects directly, as above.

Comment: I'm getting this error

undefined method `property' for #<Lease:0x007f06a824d640>

Extracted source (around line #4):

1: <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
2: <p> Firstname: <%= @tenant.name %></p>
3: <p> Start: <%= @lease.lease_start %></p>
4: <p>Property <%= @lease.property.address_line_1 %></>

Comment: Strange.. did you run your migrations and/or restarted the webserver?

Comment: As Kaeros suggests, check your migrations have all run and restart your server.

Comment: I changed the associations in the lease model to - has_one :tenant has_one :property - and then changed - belongs_to :lease -  in the tenant and property model and then changed my controller to fit it and it worked fine thanks for your help